# Window Builder forgets which files can be edited

Tags: java, eclipse, window, builder, windowbuilder

I sync my eclipse between 2 systems and sometimes Eclipse loses all the projects in the explorer. I can add them back with no problem, but then my Window Builder plugin forgets which files were created with Window Builder.

I have to create a new Window Builder file and paste the same code back into the new file that I can use Window Builder.

Is there some way I can select a Java file to tell Window Builder that it can edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import your project > Go right click on class you want to open with WB > Open with > WindowBuilder Editor

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thank you so much! This was really bothering me, and I couldn't figure out what to Google, to find a solution.